# Create a template

Tags: templates, include

Is it possible to create a template where you can import your preamble as well? How? So you have your main document which looks like:

```
\include{preamble}
\include{A}
\include{B}
\include{C}
```

And are there a reason why I not should do it? Thanks for help!

Comment: As far as I know, `\include` issues a newpage/clearpage etc, so this is some kind of 'typesetting' to be done, if you try to `\include{preamble}`, so I would guess this is not possible. You should be able to use `\input{preamble}` however

Comment: Where do you want to place your `\begin{document}...\end{document}` pair in the 'template?

Comment: I think what you want is `\input{filename}`. It merely puts the contents if the file *filename* to the position of *input*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not `\include` but you can use `\input` so if you want

```
\input{preamble}
\include{A}
\include{B}
\include{C}
\input{postamble}
```

where `preamble.tex` is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
```

and `postamble.tex` is

```
\end{document}
```

you can do that.

However I wouldn't: it obscures the form of your document.

If you want to share a lot of preamble macros in different documents I think it is better to use the form

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{local-setup}
\begin{document}
\include{A}
\include{B}
\include{C}
\end{document}
```

where `local-setup.sty` is (in this case}

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
```